# Parsing location from a search query in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, search

I have a table of location data that is stored in json format with an attributes column that contains data as below:-

```json
{
 "name" : "Common name of a place or a postcode",
 "other_name":"Any aliases",
 "country": "country"
}
```

This is indexed as follows:-

```
CREATE INDEX location_jsonb_ts_vector
ON location 
USING gin (jsonb_to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, attributes,'["string","numeric"]'::jsonb));
```

I can search this for a location using the query:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM location
WHERE  jsonb_to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, attributes, '["string", "numeric"]'::jsonb) @@ plainto_tsquery('place name')
```

This works well if just using place names. But I want to search using more complex text strings such as:-

```
'coffee shops with wifi near charing cross'
'all restaurants within 10 miles of swindon centre'
'london nightlife'
```

I want to get the location found first and then strip it from the search text and go looking for the items in other tables using my location record to narrow down the scope.

This does not work with my current search mechanism as the intent and requirement pollute the text search vector and can cause odd results. I know this is a NLP problem and needs proper parsing of the search string, but this is for a small proof of concept and needs to work entirely in postgres via SQL or PL/PGSQL.

How can I modify my search to get better matches? I've tried splitting into keywords and looking for them individually, but they risk not bring back results unless combined. For example; "Kings Cross" will bring back "Kings".

Comment: Could I create a custom dictionary for the search using only the words from my location table?

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a cheap and cheerful solution:-

```
WITH tsv AS (

    SELECT to_tsquery('english', 'football | matches | in | swindon') AS search_vector,
           'football matches in swindon' AS search_text

)

SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT attributes,
           position(lower(ATTRIBUTES->>'name1') IN lower(search_text)) AS name1_position
    FROM location,tsv
    WHERE  jsonb_to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, attributes, '["string", "numeric"]'::jsonb) @@ search_vector
) loc
ORDER BY name1_position DESC
```